# How do I add an HTML tag to the formatting drop-down in the rich text editor?

Tags: richtext, drop-down

I would like to add the 'code' tag to the formatting drop-down. My rich text field is using Standard.json and I am able to remove the current tags, but it's not letting me add additional tags. I have tried adding 'code' like this in my Standard.json file:

```
formattingTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'code', 'h1', 'h2' 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']
```

Any thoughts?

(I realize 'pre' and 'code' are similar but if possible I would like to use code to be semantic.)

Answer (score 2):

Might [formattingAdd](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#setting-formattingAdd) be something you can use for this? Not tested, just a quick look at Redactor's options page.

```
formattingAdd: [
    {
        tag: 'code',
        title: 'Code'
    }
]
```

Comment: It did not work when putting it into my Standard.json file. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Did you select Standard as the config setting for your field?

Comment: Yeah. I know it's using the Standard.json file because I can remove existing tags and they are removed from the drop-down. No worries though. I've settled for using 'pre' and it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't work because Craft is not yet on Redactor 10.0. Probably just a matter of time though. Nice find, Paul!